# Laravel Echo connects but is not Subscribing to Pusher Private Channel on prod server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, echo, pusher, laravel-echo

I have a Laravel API backend using Sanctum for auth. I'm using VueJS as the frontend with Laravel Echo to listen for broadcasted events on private channels. On my local development machine I can connect to and subscribe to a Private channel without issue. I can see this in the Pusher Debug Console.

However, on my prod server I can see that the connection is made to Pusher in the Debug Console but the subscription isn't made. I have no idea why this is... Here is my config files below:

config/broadcasting.php

```
'connections' => [
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'eu',
            // 'useTLS' => true
        ],
```

routes/channels.php - I return true to make sure it isn't the auth causing it

```
Broadcast::channel('calendar.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return true;
});
```

I have uncommented the `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` in `config/app.php` and added the Broadcast::route function to use sanctum.

```
public function boot()
{
   Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);
   require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

My frontend config in main.js (baseURL is the URL of our API, ex: https://site.oursite.com:

```
window.Pusher = require("pusher-js");
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  key: "my key",
  cluster: "eu",
  encrypted: true,
  authEndpoint: config.get("baseUrl") + "/broadcasting/auth",
  auth: {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token.getToken(1)}`,
    },
  },
});

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = config.get("baseUrl");
axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie");

let socketId = false;
window.Echo.connector.pusher.connection.bind("connected", function() {
  socketId = window.Echo.socketId();
});

//set the socket ID on each axios request
axios.interceptors.request.use((conf) => {
  // pusher socket
  if (socketId) conf.headers["X-Socket-ID"] = socketId; 

  // add auth token
  conf.baseURL = config.get("baseUrl") + "/api/";
  if (token.hasToken(1))
    conf.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token.getToken(1)}`;

  return conf;
});
```

And the listeners:

```
window.Echo.private(`calendar.${calendarId}`).listen(
  ".entry.created",
  (payload) => {
    console.log(payload);
  }
);
```

Is there anything specific that needs to be set up on production vs local development?
The only thing I can think that is different in the environments is that the prod server uses SSL whereas on local dev I do no.
I'll appreciate it if someone has any ideas that I can try.

Comment: This is likely being caused by an authentication error when trying to subscribe to the channel. You should add some logging to your auth endpoint, along with binding to the subscription_error event. See https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events#pushersubscription_error-761190603 for details of this event.

Comment: Turns out it was an env issue. We use Docker to build our Laravel containers and the env for our staging server was located in a different directory and wasn't updated accordingly before being copied once the image was being built...